# Cant get access to google bucket Invalid string value: 'noAcl:'. Allowed values: [full, noacl]

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I have created google cloud virtual image first.

I have such code:

```
>>> from google.cloud import storage 
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> client = storage.Client() 
>>> bucket = client.get_bucket('landsst')
```

However I get such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/iashrapov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 177, in get_buc
ket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "/home/iashrapov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 108, in reloa
d
    _target_object=self)
  File "/home/iashrapov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/lanst?projection=noAcl
: 606507140911-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to landsbyconst.
```

With such JSON as  output:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid string value: 'noAcl:'. Allowed values: [full, noacl]",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "projection"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid string value: 'noAcl:'. Allowed values: [full, noacl]"
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. Running same code through local PC returns error:

DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see

So initially I dont have permission error or not, hmm?

upd. I can connect to the bucket created on my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the execution of `gcloud auth application-default login` instead of `gcloud auth login solved` this 403 issue for me